# Get total "Screen On Usage" since last full charge

Tags: battery, big-sur, screen, power

On my M1 MacBook Air I can check the "Screen On Usage" for the last 10 days:
[image: Battery info]

What I would be interested in is how much time I spent actively using the machine since I last charged to 100%.
Of course I could combine the information visible here, and try to estimate from the bar chart how many minutes I have spent per day - but this is tedious and not very exact, as the axis of the lower graph only shows intervals of one hour.

Is there any better way to get this information without having to resort to commercial apps? Obviously the information I need is available, but I do not know where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I googled some more and apparently it is possible to get this information from the output of `pmset -g log`, although this is still not easy to parse.

In these log messages one can find messages like these:

```
2021-07-14 17:59:16 +0200 Notification          Display is turned off
```

```
2021-07-14 17:59:47 +0200 Notification          Display is turned on
```

as well as messages including the current charge:

```
2021-07-08 22:56:24 +0200 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 USB-C_plug/ Using AC (Charge:100%) 6 secs
```

So I wrote a small Python script to parse these log messages and compute the total time of the display turned on since the laptop was last unplugged.

If anyone is interested, the code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/DudeNr33/screen-on-time).

But if there are better/easier/fancier alternatives out there, I'm still interested in trying them out!